# Good backend for downloading nzb files to seperate directories

Tags: python, network-programming, xml-rpc, nntp, usenet

I'm laying out a download management that will segregate each users downloads, separate watched directories each download to their own folders, can't see each others queues, etc.

I wanted to use Hellanzb with xml-rpc, however it does not seem to allow me to set separate download directories for each file. I want to avoid trying to guess where it goes from the file names, but if that is the best option then so be it.

Could you suggest any applicable libraries or programs I could tie to?

Thanks, Chance

Answer (score -1):

I'd check out http://github.com/maddox/pyrot. It may do what you need.

Comment: It appears to categorize the files after downloading based on their name and extension, whereas I want to assign a base directory beforehand based on what user submitted the file. Thanks for the suggestion though, I may see if I can use the users ID as a prefix to the nzb, then if that gets translated to the download directory I can relocated the directory as needed.